# Two Level Menus in Hugo

Tags: web, hugo, static-site-generation

I want to create a site with deep menus using Hugo. I want the ability to make child items parents to new lower-level items.
I tried using this site's tutorial.
https://codingnconcepts.com/hugo/nested-menu-hugo/

I am able to create one-level submenus, but I want a logic system that I can continue to create subpages with automatically.

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
        <li class="{{ if $currentPage.HasMenuCurrent "main" . }}active{{ end }}">
            <span>{{ .Name }}</span>
            {{ if .HasChildren }}
            <span class="drop-icon" for="{{ .Name }}">▾</span>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                {{ range .Children }}
                <li class="{{ if $currentPage.HasMenuCurrent "main" . }}active{{ end }}">
                    <span>{{ .Name }}</span>
                </li>
                {{ end }}
            </ul>
           {{ end }}
        </li>
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This sample above creates one submenu, but I can't figure out how to make two levels work.

Answer (score 2):

in config.toml:

```
[menu]

[[menu.main]]
name = "home"
identifier = "home"
url = "/home/"

[[menu.main]]
parent = "home"
name = "about"
identifier = "about"
url = "/about/"

[[menu.main]]
parent = "home"
name = "contact"
identifier = "contact"
url = "/contact/"
```

Then your template - from [docs](https://gohugo.io/templates/menu-templates/)

```
<aside>
    <ul>
        {{ $currentPage := . }}
        {{ range .Site.Menus.main }}
            {{ if .HasChildren }}
                <li class="{{ if $currentPage.HasMenuCurrent "main" . }}active{{ end }}">
                    <a href="#">
                        {{ .Pre }}
                        <span>{{ .Name }}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    {{ range .Children }}
                        <li class="{{ if $currentPage.IsMenuCurrent "main" . }}active{{ end }}">
                            <a href="{{ .URL }}">{{ .Name }}</a>
                        </li>
                    {{ end }}
                </ul>
            {{ else }}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ .URL }}">
                        {{ .Pre }}
                        <span>{{ .Name }}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Have a nice one